# XPaths with PHP rel="i need this value"

Tags: php, html, xml, xpath

I'm using XPaths to get data.

How can I get `rel="this value with xpaths"`

```
<input type="button" style="width: 120px !important"
       class="followButton  quest" value="subscribe" 
       rel="548484545">
```

I need the rel="**548484545**"

So far I've tried something like:

```
$xpath = new DOMXPath( $html );
        $nodelist = $xpath->query( "//input//#class=/" );

            foreach ($nodelist as $n){

            echo $n->nodeValue; 
    }
```

But as I understand I'm not dealing with nodes in this case?
Am I right?

Comment: `//input[@rel="548484545"]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to select node `<input>` with 'rel=548484545', use this pattern:

```
//input[@rel="548484545"]
```

Otherwise, if you want select all `<input>` with attribute 'rel' and retrieve 'rel' values:

```
foreach( $xpath->query('//input/@rel') as $rel )
{
    echo $rel->nodeValue; # result: 548484545
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This XPath expression

```
//input[@value='subscribe']/@rel
```

will select

```
548484545
```